# Is there an Excel function which only averages column values when its row does not contain non-numeric values?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a dataset in Excel, which has some NaN values in it.
The problem is I should get the average the columns, but I can't calculate with the rows which has NaN value in it.
How can I solve this problem using functions? (The dataset has few hundred rows, I don't want to do it manually.)

Here is the example:

[image: Example]

I don't want Wed and Thu in the average, so A option would be (15+4+7)/3 and B would be (9+4+1)/3.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `AVERAGEIFS()` function.

```
=AVERAGEIFS(B$2:B$6,$B$2:$B$6,"<>Nan",$C$2:$C$6,"<>Nan")
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The `AVERAGE` function already ignores the text cells. You just select the range and it will automatically exclude the cells that contain text from the calculations. Test it on a small range and see it for yourself.